# Crear Listas dentro de otra Lista en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7

Hola me tope con un problema que no se como resolverlo, lo que yo quiero lograr es conseguir meter una lista(A) dentro de otra lista(B), pero quiero que ese proceso se repita X veces y esten separadas las listas(B).
en si lo que quiero crear es esto

```
lista=[['dato1','dato2']['Dato3','dato4']]
```

crear una función que agregue listas que contengan datos diatónicamente y los datos los ingreso con un input

Comment: Por favor incluyas los codigos ó metodos que ha probado

Comment: Falta texto y código para que podamos entender mejor la pregunta, y creo ademas, que las etiquetas están mal puestas. creo que sobra la etiqueta de python-2.7. Al codigo le falta una coma, entre las dos listas internas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las listas en Python tienen el método append() para añadir items. Si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer es añadir listas a una lista (una lista de listas, vaya). Primero crea las listas que van a ir dentro, y luego añádelas a la lista principal.

```
main_list = [] 

inner_list1 = [] 
inner_list1.append("dato1")
inner_list1.append("dato2") 

inner_list2 = [] 
inner_list2.append("dato3")
inner_list2.append("dato4")

main_list.append(inner_list1)
main_list.append(inner_list2)
```

También la puedes crear así:

```
main_list = [ ["dato1", "dato2"], ["dato3", "dato4"] ]
```

Para ayudarte con la función necesito más información.